# Ruby Nokogiri converting KML to CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, nokogiri, kml

I'm trying to extract two different elements from a KML file and turn them into a CSV. I'm starting with the great site here: http://ckdake.com/content/2012/highgroove-hack-night-kml-heatmaps.html that generates a csv of coordinates. All I want to do now is add the name tag to the start of each line. I'm a ruby/nokogiri n00b so I can stick this bit of code in which gets me a) a list of all names followed by b) a list of all coordinates. But again - I'd like them on the same line.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri' # gem install nokogiri

@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("WashingtonDC2013-01-04 12h09m01s.kml"))

@doc.css('name').each do |name|  
  puts name.content
end

@doc.css('coordinates').each do |coordinates|
  coordinates.text.split(' ').each do |coordinate|
    (lat,lon,elevation) = coordinate.split(',')
    puts "#{lat},#{lon}\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
@doc.css('Placemark').each do |placemark|
  name = placemark.css('name')
  coordinates = placemark.at_css('coordinates')

  if name && coordinates
    print name.text + ","
    coordinates.text.split(' ').each do |coordinate|
      (lon,lat,elevation) = coordinate.split(',')
      print "#{lat},#{lon}"
    end
    puts "\n"
  end
end
```

I'm assuming here that there is one coordinates pair in the `<coordinates>` tags for each `<Placemark>`. If there are more, they'll all get appended onto the same line.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to post some of the KML file itself so I can test on it. I'm just guessing based on [this sample KML file](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CD0QFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fkml%2Fdocumentation%2FKML_Samples.kml&ei=xbrrUKC5PIzdkgWcx4CQAw&usg=AFQjCNFXvmR0VXT1YNLH1irpbZAkJE1TYg&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.dGI&cad=rja).

Comment: Careful, coordinates in KML are (longitude, latitude, elevation). Updated the code to reflect that. https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#coordinates